# How can i prove the following Infinite Product?

Tags: riemann-zeta, infinite-product

I understand how to derive the Euler Product over primes for the Zeta function using the sieving method. However, upon reading more it said the following..

$$\prod_{P Prime}^{\infty}(1-p^{-s})^{-1} = \prod_{P Prime}^{\infty}(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p^{-ns})= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}  $$

So my question is , how is it possible to directly prove that the product  of that geometric series is equal to the zeta function sum? Does the use of the geometric series involve a different proof than the one usually given which uses the sieving?

Thank you for your help a lot.

Comment: Sure; think of the unique factorization theorem. When I proved it in class, I looked at a partial product (where the terms were the geometric series) and compared it to the sum.

Comment: All the proofs are the same. Note $\prod_{p \le k} (\sum_{m=0}^\infty (p^m)^{-s})= \sum_{n=1, Lpf(n) \le k}^\infty n^{-s}$ where $Lpf$ is the largest prime factor